# Licence manager integration with Installshield for WPF application

Tags: wpf, installshield

How to integrate Quick Licence Manager with InstallShield for creating licence?
I have an WPF application for which I need to issue license keys. Need to integrate QLM with Installshield.

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge module option in Installshiled. Refer below links.
http://soraco.co/Forum/tabid/68/forumid/4/postid/8/scope/posts/Default.aspx
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpMergeModules.htm